# Not sure how to tag this riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I was born in the forest with my boy Lew
>   Growing up I learned science at Roosevelt's zoo
>   Dined with the devil then got my life on track
>   Made a lot of money and never gave any back
>   Now I'm retired and brush shoulders with rappers
>   I'll die in Jamaica surrounded by nappers

Hint:

> My friends and I beat knaves, kings, and mimes
>  Best to stand clear when you hear my chimes

Hint 2:

> I'm surprised there is such a delay in solving this riddle. It was meant to be the express version!

Hint 3:

> Finally figured out how to tag this riddle: "large", "pomaceous"

Hint 4:

> Hint in response to @jmoriarty's guess
>
>  My name is not spoken by pirates, @jmoriarty!
>  But my friends and I do initial a Mr. Roy G.

Comment: Hi! Welcoming to Puzzling! I tend to suggest riddles do some sort of play on words or reference to the final answer in a riddle to help confirm the answer.

Comment: Are you referring to the title? It is related to the content of the riddle :)

Comment: Well then, I've already been deceived!

Comment: Added a tag. If not required, kindly remove.

Comment: Sounds like it could be some sort of name that fits various lines.. E.g Clark to go with Lewis in a forest.

Comment: Chimes- I feel like that gives a big clue. Although I can't think of anything that chimes besides a grandfather clock for some reason...

Comment: Friends who beat cards - maybe Cardinals (sports teams)?  Line 3 - the play/musical "Damn Yankees"?

Comment: @Eric Perhaps another hint is in order?

Comment: @jmoriarty you are like 95% of the way there :) I just added another hint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> A (New York City Subway service).

Not sure how to tag this riddle

> I imagine a train, especially a moving one, would be quite challenging to tag (graffiti).

I was born in the forest with my boy Lew

> The A-line begins in Inwood, Manhatten. Inwood sounds like "in wood", hence "in the forest". Not sure about the "with my boy Lew" part.

Growing up I learned science at Roosevelt's zoo

> The A-line passes the American Museum of Natural History, situated in Theodore Roosevelt Park.

Dined with the devil then got my life on track

> The A-line has a stop in Hell's Kitchen, Manhattan.

Made a lot of money and never gave any back

> The A-line has a stop in Financial District, Manhattan.

Now I'm retired and brush shoulders with rappers

> In Brooklyn, the A-line briefly crosses the path of the J/Z-line. From these letters we may be brushing shoulders with rappers Jay Z and AZ.

I'll die in Jamaica surrounded by nappers

> One of three potential final stops for the A-line is in Rockaway Park, which borders *Jamaica* Bay. The depot for the A-line is the Pitkin Yard, though there is a depot called the Jamaica Yard. Train tracks rest on railway *sleepers*, hence "surrounded by nappers".

My friends and I beat knaves, kings, and mimes

> "My friends and I" are the trains using the IND Eighth Avenue Line: A, C, E. In most card games an ace is ranked higher than a knave or a king. Not sure what a mime is.

Best to stand clear when you hear my chimes

> When you hear the whistle of a train approaching you are told to 'stand clear'.

I'm surprised there is such a delay in solving this riddle. It was meant to be the express version!

> The A-line's full name is the "A Eighth Avenue *Express*".

Finally figured out how to tag this riddle: "large", "pomaceous"

> The Big Apple (New York).

My name is not spoken by pirates, @jmoriarty!
But my friends and I do initial a Mr. Roy G.

> So, not the R-line, as I previously thought. Mr. Roy G. appears to be an illusion to ROYGBIV, a common acronym for the sequence of hues in a rainbow (red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet). The colour of the IND Eighth Avenue Line trains is blue. Alternatively, IND are the first three letters of indigo.

Comment: You are so close! It is another trainline that is not the R. The correct answer fits these hints better: I was born in the forest with my boy Lew, Growing up I learned science at Roosevelt's zoo, Now I'm retired and brush shoulders with rappers, My friends and I beat knaves, kings, and mimes

Comment: @Eric I've updated my answer to reflect your most recent hint. Still can't figure out the "rapper" and "Jamaica" clues.

Comment: You got it! It looks like you figured out the rapper and Jamaica clues in your edits. The nappers part is a reference to the people still on the train at the end.

Comment: @Eric Can you explain the "my boy Lew" and "mimes" parts?

Comment: Lew Alcindor is the birth name of famous athlete born in Inwood (later known as Kareem Abdul-Jabbar). Mimes are the joker card in a deck. I will admit that one is a bit of a stretch to get a rhyme.

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

You are

> Usain Bolt

I was born in the forest with my boy Lew:

> According to Wiki, Bolt was born in "Sherwood." Not sure about Lew.

Growing up I learned science at Roosevelt's zoo:

> Something about the White House. Apparently Teddy Roosevelt had quite the menagerie.

Dined with the devil before getting my life on track

> He runs track. Don't know about the devil.

Made a lot of money and never gave any back:

> Was never busted for steroids, so got to keep his winnings

Now I'm retired and brush shoulders with rappers

> He did meet his idol JayZ recently, who also sings "brush your shoulders off"

I'll die in Jamaica surrounded by nappers

> He is from Jamaica, a fitting place for him to die

Title:

> Fast people are hard to tag.

Comment: A good attempt! Your guess for one of the clues is correct, but the solution is not very close to your guess.

Comment: Dang. Thought I was on to something. Some of it fit really well, but the rest was a super weird fit.